# how awk seen option works

Tags: awk

I have recently come across an awk *seen* option. I can see it is removing duplicates in files. I could use some clarification on how it works.

```
cat tes
1
2
3
1
1
1
3
4
```

with awk seen output

```
cat tes | awk '!seen[$0]++'

1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 10):

`seen` is the arbitrary name of an associative array. It is not an option of any kind. You could use `a` or `b` or most other names in its place.

The code `!seen[$0]++` consists of a test and an increment.

If `seen[$0]`, i.e. the value of the array element associated with the key `$0`, the current line of input, is zero (or empty), then the boolean value of `!seen[$0]` is *true*.

The value in the array corresponding to the key `$0` is then incremented, which means that the test will be *false* all other times that the same value of `$0` is found.

The effect is that the test is *true* the first time a particular line is seen in the input, and *false* all other times.

Whenever the a test with no associated action is *true*, the *default* action is triggered.  The default action is the equivalent of `{ print }` or `{ print $0 }`, which prints the current record, which for all accounts and purposes in this example is the current unmodified line of input.

Comment: Changing the $0 can extend the capabilities of this expression. For example, indexing by $5 lists lines with at most one instance of field 5, indexing by $2 FS $4 is unique on two non-adjacent fields.